# Java compilation error on method signature

Tags: java

So I'm trying to get my display method to work...

```
private static displayResults(String gender,int age,String rateResult);
{
    System.out.Println("Thank you");
    System.out.println("the "+ gender + " is " + age + " years old.");
    System.out.println("the rate class is: " + rateResult);
}
```

**My Error____ ps/ took out string but i get the same error.... what am i missing??**

```
RentalRates.java:163: error: illegal start of expression

private static String displayResults(gender,int age,rateResult);
^
RentalRates.java:163: error: illegal start of expression

private static String displayResults(gender,int age,rateResult);
           ^
RentalRates.java:163: error: ';' expected

private static String displayResults(gender,int age,rateResult);
                    ^
RentalRates.java:163: error: '.class' expected

private static String displayResults(gender,int age,rateResult);
                                                   ^
RentalRates.java:163: error: ';' expected

private static String displayResults(gender,int age,rateResult);
                                                  ^
RentalRates.java:163: error: not a statement

private static String displayResults(gender,int age,rateResult);
                                                   ^
RentalRates.java:163: error: ';' expected

private static String displayResults(gender,int age,rateResult);
                                                             ^
RentalRates.java:169: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
```

Comment: remove the `;` from the end of the method declaration

Comment: like next to rate result?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't be suprised when `displayResults` was written in another method like in your first question. The error messages are pretty much the same.

Comment: Did my answer solve your question?

Answer (score 1):

You essentially ended the method here before you made it do anything, and then put a block after it:

```
private static displayResults(String gender, int age, String rateResult); // ; ends method declaration
{ //Creates new, function-less and illegal block
```

That semicolon ends the method. Get rid of that, and put `void` after `static`. This means that your method has no return type (as there is no `return` statement in your block).

```
private static void displayResults(String gender, int age, String rateResult) { ...
```

Comment: thanks I think that helped some but i get illegal start still

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

- Remove the semicolon from the method's signature
- declare it as `public` (as from what the error message depicts, it's being called from another class)
- declare a return type in the method's signature (i.e. `int`, `String`, etc., but for your case, is `void`).

This results in the below format:

```
public static void displayResults(String gender,int age,String rateResult) {
    System.out.Println("Thank you");
    System.out.println("the "+ gender + " is " + age + " years old.");
    System.out.println("the rate class is: " + rateResult);
}
```

**A bit of more explained answer**
Just remove the semicolon from the method's signature as this is the basic compilation error from a first view. On the other hand, your method doesn't have a return type. If this is the way you want to implement it (i.e. just do a typical thing like printing a message, for example), you have to declare it with a `void` type -> `private static void displayResults(String gender,int age,String rateResult) { }`.  Also take a look at [Defining Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

But, for the case you are defining it as static and it just logs some messages (ok, I won't criticise the purpose of this requirement <- having a method for 3 lines of logging), it seems to be a helper method, which means that should be better defined as `public static` (and not `private`), in order to let other classes access it without creating an instance of the specified class.

*I assume that's what you want to achieve: calling this method from another class (let's say `MainClass.java`). Then that will work:*

`MainClass.java`

```
...
Utils.displayResults(gender, age, rateResult);
...
```

And the helper class (say `Utils.java`) could have several helper methods, like the one depicted in your question.

`Utils.java`

```
...
public static void displayResults(String gender,int age,String rateResult) {    }
...
```

But this is just an assumption of your possible design,as you didn't explain what you want to achieve. So, for further reference, I would suggest also reading generally about [methods](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/JavaSyntax/methods.html), understanding the examples and how your problem could be approached for these ones, and then come back again, if you think something is still not clear enough (, but in any case, I would generally suggest, **learning the language first and then coming here,** **for mature questions**).